# using lazy C++ for stub generation

Tags: lazy-c++, stub-data-generation

Have you ever used lazy C++?

I am trying to create .CPP files out of .H files. In forum I read that it is possible with your tool but I tried touse it and I didn't succeed.
Can you help me?

I used the option -c with a Test.h file with exactly the following declaration.

```
class TEST_A
{
public:
  TEST_A();
  ~TEST_A();

void fooA( MyNamespace::String& aName );
};
```

The only thing I have is a Cpp file with written

```
#define LZZ_INLINE
#undef LZZ_INLINE
```

and the .h file modified with  before the class

```
#define LZZ_LINE inline
class TEST_A
{
public:
  TEST_A();
  ~TEST_A();

void fooA( MyNamespace::String& aName );
};
#undef LZZ_LINE
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong.

First of all better to rename the .h file into .lzz

LZZ is able to go from an header file having a COMPLETE class declaration/definition to a couple of file .h and .cpp.

For what I need to do I have first to add manually the curly brackets if I want to achieve my goal.